# Como realizo respaldos automaticos diarios en SQL SERVER 2005

Tags: sql, base-de-datos

Tengo una base de datos en SQL SERVER 2005 que necesito respaldar a diario, esta versión de SQL no cuenta con el SQL Agent, por lo que no se puede programar un programa automatico.
Impelemte el siguiente Query que ejecutado directo en el Server Management me crea el respaldo

```
DECLARE @fecha VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @archivo VARCHAR(50)
SET @fecha = CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), DAY(GETDATE()))+'-'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), MONTH(GETDATE()))+'-'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), YEAR(GETDATE()))
SET @archivo = 'R:\Backup\Respaldo_'+ @fecha +'.bak'
ALTER DATABASE MiDB SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
BACKUP DATABASE MiDB TO DISK = @archivo
ALTER DATABASE MiDB SET MULTI_USER
GO
```

el problema es cuando quiero ejecutar este script mediante un .BAT, me genera un error y no me crea el respaldo:

```
SQLCMD -S MIHOST\MSSQLSERVER -E -i "C:\BATS\backup.sql"
```

este error me genera al ejecutar el archivo .BAT:
"HResult 0x57, Level 16, State 1
SQL Network Interfaces: Connection string is not valid [87].
"

Comment: El problema es tu cadena de conexión. Por el nombre de la instancia, es probable que no sea una instancia nombrada. En ese caso, solo va el nombre del servidor.

Comment: ¿Estás ejecutándolo en el propio servidor o desde un cliente remoto?

Comment: desde el propio SERVER

Answer (score 1):

El problema es tu cadena de conexión. Por el nombre de la instancia, es probable que no sea una instancia nombrada. En ese caso, solo va el nombre del servidor.

Intenta con esto.

```
SQLCMD -S MIHOST -E -i "C:\BATS\backup.sql"
```

Answer (score 0):

Al final no me complique tanto, y encontre otra forma con igual con un .bat, que programe para que se ejecute a diario.

```
@echo off
set FECHA=%date%
set FECHA=%FECHA:/=%
set FECHA=%FECHA: =%
set FECHA=%FECHA::=%
set FECHA=%FECHA:,=%

SQLCMD -S HOSTNAME,1433 -U user -P pasword -Q "BACKUP DATABASE nombreBD TO DISK = 'D:\Backup_%FECHA%.bak' WITH INIT, NAME = N'Backup Automatico de database', STATS = 10"
```